# Solving logistic differential equation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that the logistic differential equation is

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=kx-\lambda x^2$$

The above logistic law is assume to be no emigration!

$$k=\frac{1}{400}$$

$$\lambda=10^{-8}$$

$x$ is human population at year $t$!

An island consist of human population such that the 100 human emigrates out of the island to the mainland yearly. Modify the differential equation such that it includes the emigration of human! It is stated that the human population at the year of $1980$ is $20,000$.

My attempt is

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=k(x-100)-\lambda (x-100)^2$$

But to no avail my attempt fail!
The answer given at the back is 
$$x=\frac{(10^5)[3e^{\frac{15}{10^4}(1980-t)}-2]}{6e^{\frac{15}{10^4}(1980-t))}-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

Your modification should be $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = kx-\lambda x^2 - 100$.

Then, you have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\lambda x^2 - kx + 100}=-dt$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I thought it should be $x-100$ since the population decreases 100 people yearly and then x is the number of human population.

Comment: Not quite. The logistic differential relationship still holds. Now, we just add in the -100, so that it represents the yearly emigration rates

Comment: Thanks and I will try it.

Comment: @Crazy think about the original $x(t)$ however. With emigration it would be $x(t) = \text{stuff } - 100t$ (_100 people leave per year (__t__)_). Differentiate with respect to $t$ and you get $x'(t) = \frac{d(\text{stuff})}{dt} - 100$, which is where the 100 comes from.

Comment: Thanks that is very straightforward for me to get the gist of it!!